# Django Rest Framework: Pickle Response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-redis

What I'm trying to do is build a custom version of [`cache_page`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#django.views.decorators.cache.cache_page) where I have more control over the cache key, but I'm getting stuck with even the basic caching of my response:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

from app import models

class BaseViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = models.Items.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Items.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        response = Response({})
        cache.set('test', response, 10)
        return response
```

Where the relevant parts of my `settings.py` are setup as:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS': 'rest_framework.versioning.NamespaceVersioning'
}
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": f"redis://127.0.0.1:6729/1",
    },
}
```

When I try to call the endpoint I get:

```
django.template.response.ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be pickled.
```

Then if I change the line to:

```
cache.set('test', response.render(), 10)
```

I get:

```
AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response
```

(If I set the renderer it complains about the accepted media, then the context and finally fails with `TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable`)

Despite the fact that the API call itself works fine without the caching.

[`cache_page`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#django.views.decorators.cache.cache_page) actually works fine, so I know it's possible to cache the response, but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by having the view return a `django.http.JsonResponse` rather than a `rest_framework.response.Response` object. The problem is that the rest_framework `Response` is mediatype agnostic, and as far as I can tell relies on having the renderer and accepted media values set further down the call chain of the view, after it has left your handler. Since `JsonResponse` only deals with json, it doesn't have to go through this ["content negotiation"](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation/).

Answer (score 0):

[cache_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#django.views.decorators.cache.cache_page)

work because of this:

```
if hasattr(response, 'render') and callable(response.render):
            response.add_post_render_callback(lambda r: self.cache.set(cache_key, r, timeout))
        else:
            self.cache.set(cache_key, response, timeout)
```